# How to change installation directory for Android Studio, and what are the consequences?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, software-installation, hard-drive, android

When installing Android Studio on Ubuntu (18.04.5), the default installation folder is in the same drive as the OS. I don't have enough storage for this* so I'm trying to install on another drive, but I can't seem to do that. Most of the other posts say that you can always move the directory after it installs(in fact, this seems to be preferred since A-Studio prefers opt(?)), but I can't even do that due to lack of space, and I can't make space either (space is occupied by the OS; I have most of my files in the other drive). I'm a bit stumped because of this, and also because from what I've read, it seems like the folder has to be in the same drive as the OS to work properly. Do I just need to make space somehow? (i.e., move the OS to my other drive which has a lot more space. It is currently in an SSD and I didn't want to move it to the other one, which is HDD.)

*I tried and the installation failed, and next time I booted, I had to go into recovery mode to delete the directory because Ubuntu wouldn't finish booting due to lack of space.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try installing Android Studio by [downloading a `.zip` file](https://developer.android.com/studio) then [extract it where you want](https://developer.android.com/studio/install)?

Comment: yes lol but I have to execute a file that installs a bunch of SDK components without letting me change the directory. (#4 in this list: https://developer.android.com/studio/install#linux)

Comment: Thank you for the follow-up. You should try to [create a symlink](https://wiki.debian.org/SymLink) for this directory pointing to your other drive. Good luck!

Comment: I'll give it a shot! Thanks.

Comment: Eventually something strange happened where the executable was working but the SDK was not installed... I was prompted to set up the necessary files and I was finally able to change the directory! But thanks a bunch for your time, I'm a ubuntu newbie so I'll definitely look into your solution, just to get familiar with these things.

Comment: Nevermind; it was super-buggy so I restarted my computer and I'm back to square one.

Comment: Glad to hear this, have fun!